# System.exit(0) not working & Object Oriented Design.

Tags: java, oop

I am writing a simple java program to perform **Addition** and **Multiplication** using **Object Oriented technique**. First it asks about the operation Addition, Multiplication or Exit. When  Addition and Multiplication button is pressed it gets two numbers from user, performs the task and gives the result.But my **problem is when Exit button is pressed it does not terminates instead it ask for numbers.**
And second thing which i want to ask is that am i following the **Object Oriented approach**.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Calculator {

private static int number1;
private static int number2;

public static void setNumber1(int n1) {
    number1 = n1;
}
public static void setNumber2(int n2) {
    number2 = n2;
}
public static int getNumber1() {
    return number1;
}

public static int getNumber2() {
    return number2;
}

public static void numbers(){
    int n=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter first number:"));
    int nn=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter first number:"));
    setNumber1(n);
    setNumber2(nn);
}
public static void calculate(int o){
    switch(o){
    case 0:
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Addition is  :"+(number1+number2));
        break;
    case 1:
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Product is  :"+(number1*number2));
        break;
    case 2:
        System.exit(0);
        break;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Custom button text
    Object[] options = {"Addition","Product", "Exit!"};
    int op = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"What operation Would you like to perform ?","Addition or Product Calculator",
                                         JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                                         null,options,options[2]);

    Calculator c=new Calculator();
    c.numbers();
    c.calculate(op);
}
```

}

Comment: seeing all these `static methods`, I vote for **no** on the OOP. The only static method you should have here is `main`.

Comment: But that part of the question should go on `Code Review`. http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You call first `c.numbers();` and then `c.calculate(op);` so that's why it does not exit before asking for numbers. Change this order if you want other functionality

Comment: **No** for OOP it is just static methods or anything else ?

Comment: @user4687489 Do you know what `static` means?

Comment: static means you can't change the value once it is set of that method or variable

Comment: You should check what `static` really means. Spoiler: it is not the same as `final`. But if you think that ... isn't it strange that you can declare `number1` as `static` and change it's value in the `setNumber1` method?

Comment: Ohh..! i guess my code also has some conceptual issues. You are right Tom

Comment: how can if first call the calculate(); when this has to use the values it gets from numbers(); ..??

Comment: @user4687489 remove `c.numbers();` from the main method and add `numbers();` to the cases `1` and `2` in your `switch` statement.

Comment: what if by it placing  it before switch statement in calculate function..!

Comment: @user4687489 And how should this solve your problem? You're still requesting the numbers before checking if the user want to exit the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that your program wont exit is that you are calling the `numbers` method which reads the numbers before the checking options in the `calculate` method. So you can prevent calling of `numbers` method when `op = 2` by checking it with an `if`.
code to do that is:

```
Calculator c=new Calculator();
if(op!=2) {
   c.numbers();
}
c.calculate(op);
```

Comment: @user4687489 That is also correct. There are other ways also to do this. You can do this as you wish.

Comment: this is how it worked: if(op==2){
   System.exit(0);
  }
  else{
   c.numbers();
   c.calculate(op);
  }

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it asks for numbers is because you are calling the method **numbers()** before 
**calculate(int o)**. You have to switch the order but with some modifications to your code.

And about OOP, Java is purely OOP. But to get the most out of it read and exercise more on the object oriented concepts like inheritance, interfaces ...